# After setting bootstrap picker popup to 'mm/yy' format, bootstrap calendar popup reverts back to 'mm/dd/yy' if textbox is selected again

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have multiple DateTimePickers on an particular page, one of them (#divSampleMonth)I have limited to 'MM/YY'. The issue is that while this works on pageload, if I click inside that particular asp.Textbox then outside of it, the next time I click within that textbox the pop-up will show the calendar days as well. This is regardless or not if I make a selection the first time the pop-up appears.

I assume the has to do with some type of order of operations, but my Javascripting is fairly poor at this point and I am not quite sure how to resolve this.

My Code:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    $('#divApplicationDate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
    });

    $('#divApplicationDate input').click(function (event) {
        $('#divApplicationDate').data("DateTimePicker").show();
    });

    $('#divEffectiveDate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
    });
    $('#divEffectiveDate input').click(function (event) {
        $('#divEffectiveDate').data("DateTimePicker").show();
    });

    $('#divDispositionDate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
    });
    $('#divDispositionDate input').click(function (event) {
        $('#divDispositionDate').data("DateTimePicker").show();
    });

    $('#divPaymentDate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
    });
    $('#divPaymentDate input').click(function (event) {
        $('#divPaymentDate').data("DateTimePicker").show();
    });

    $('#divServiceBeginDate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
    });
    $('#divServiceBeginDate input').click(function (event) {
        $('#divServiceBeginDate').data("DateTimePicker").show();
    });

    $('#divServiceEndDate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
    });
    $('#divServiceEndDate input').click(function (event) {
        $('#divServiceEndDate').data("DateTimePicker").show();
    });

    $('#divSampleMonth').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/YY',
        viewMode: "months"
    });
    $('#divSampleMonth input').click(function (event) {
        $('#divSampleMonth').data("DateTimePicker").show();
    });
    $('select').selectpicker();
}
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Have you tried switching it up by specifying the data format in the HTML as opposed to setting with JavaScript, like `<input class="datepicker" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">`? (That example is from the BS docs.)  Your code looks good, but perhaps just trying another angle might work for you.  If not, suggest you get rid of all but one datepicker; get that one working as you need it to, then do the others.

Comment: I do already have the format specified like you suggest, though with "mm/yy" along with a MaxLength= 5. I may end up just using a simple Textbox without the bootstrap if I cannot figure this out.